# NSubstitute Returns method and arrays

Tags: c#, nunit, tdd, nsubstitute

so I want to test roll results of dice set, but i can't pass an array as arg in Returns method like this:

```
    [TestCase(new[]{2, 2, 3, 1, 5}, Category.Yahtzee, 0)]
    public void AddPoints_ForGivenCategory_PointsAreStored(
        int[] rollResults, Category selectedCategory, int expectedScore)
    {
        _randomizer.GetRandomNumber(MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE).Returns(rollResults); //<-rollResults not allowed
        IDice[] dice = MakeNewDiceSet();

        _game.NewGame("A");
        _game.RollDice(dice);
        _game.AddPoints(selectedCategory);
        var result = _game.GameStatus().First()[selectedCategory];

        Assert.AreEqual(expectedScore, result);
    }
```

any tips or workarounds for this problem? Or am I forced to do this:

```
    [TestCase(2, 2, 3, 1, 5, Category.Yahtzee, 0)]
    public void AddPoints_ForGivenCategory_PointsAreStored(
        int die1, int die2, int die3, int die4, int die5, Category selectedCategory, int expectedScore)
    {
        _randomizer.GetRandomNumber(MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE).Returns(die1, die2, die3, die4, die5);
        IDice[] dice = MakeNewDiceSet();
        / ...
    }
```

Using NSubstitute v3.1.0.0

Comment: is `_randomizer.GetRandomNumber(MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE)` suppose to return a single number or array?

Comment: @Nkosi it returns int.

Comment: it is seeing the `int[]` and trying to return that as teh result which will fail as it expects single int. you can try returning function as a workaround, using a counter for the array index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSubstitute does not have `Returns<T>(T[] values)` (or similar). Instead it has `Returns<T>(T initialValue, params T[] otherValues)` to indicate we should always specify at least one value to return. The aim at the time was to avoid the potentially confusing case of stubbing a call with "no values" in the case of an empty collection. (Is it a no-op? Or does it clear the call?)

There are a few ways to get the behaviour you want. One way is to split the values into "first" and "rest":

```
random.GetRandomNumber(1, 10)
      .Returns(rollResults.First(), rollResults.Skip(1).ToArray());
```

Another approach is to use a [Queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.queue) and stub `GetRandomNumber()` to consume this:

```
var rolls = new Queue<int>(rollResults);           
random.GetRandomNumber(1, 10).Returns(_ => rolls.Dequeue());
```

If this is something you need frequently it might be worth creating your own `Returns` extension that explicitly defines how the empty case should be handled.

Comment: Will `Returns<T>(T[] values)` be implemented in the future or no chance?

Comment: @H3ll0 You are welcome to [request the feature](https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/issues/new). I'm not sure it is worth implementing due the potential ambiguity with empty arrays and as there are simple alternatives, but other collaborators may feel differently. So probably worth discussing. :)

Comment: An advantage of the queue approach is that you get an exception if another value is requested.